# Storm-kafka-mongoDB integration

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, performance-testing, apache-storm

I am reading 500 MB random tuples from Kafka producer continuous and in a storm topology I am inserting it to MongoDb using Mongo Java Driver. The problem is I am getting really low throughput as 4-5 tuples per second.

Without DB insert if I write a simple print statement I get throughput as 684 tuples per second. I am planning to run 1Million records from Kafka and check the throughput  with mongo insert.

I tried to tune using config setMaxSpoutPending , setMessageTimeoutSecs parms in kafkaconfig.

```
   final SpoutConfig kafkaConf = new SpoutConfig(zkrHosts, kafkaTopic, zkRoot, clientId);
    kafkaConf.ignoreZkOffsets=false;
    kafkaConf.useStartOffsetTimeIfOffsetOutOfRange=true;
    kafkaConf.startOffsetTime=kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime();
    kafkaConf.stateUpdateIntervalMs=2000;
    kafkaConf.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
    final TopologyBuilder topologyBuilder = new TopologyBuilder();
    topologyBuilder.setSpout("kafka-spout", new KafkaSpout(kafkaConf), 1);
    topologyBuilder.setBolt("print-messages", new MyKafkaBolt()).shuffleGrouping("kafka-spout");
     Config conf = new Config();
     conf.setDebug(true);
     conf.setMaxSpoutPending(1000);
     conf.setMessageTimeoutSecs(30);
```

Execute method of bolt

```
      JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
    jObj.put("key", input.getString(0));

        if (null !=jObj && jObj.size() > 0 ) {
            final DBCollection quoteCollection = dbConnect.getConnection().getCollection("stormPoc");
            if (quoteCollection != null) {
                BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
                dbObject.putAll(jObj);
                quoteCollection.insert(dbObject);
            //  logger.info("inserted in Collection !!!");
            } else {
                logger.info("Error while inserting data in DB!!!");
            }
            collector.ack(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `storm-mongodb` module for integration with Mongo. Does it not do the job? https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/b07413670fa62fec077c92cb78fc711c3bda820c/external/storm-mongodb

You shouldn't use `storm-kafka` for Kafka integration, it is deprecated. Use `storm-kafka-client` instead.

Setting `conf.setDebug(true)` will impact your processing, as Storm will log a fairly huge amount of text per tuple.